# React-router transitionTo is not a function

Tags: react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link, Navigation } from 'react-router';

export default class ResourceCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div onClick={this.routeHandler.bind(this)}>
                LINK
                </div>                  
        );
    }
    routeHandler(){
        this.transitionTo('someRoute', {objectId: 'asdf'})
    }
}
```

I can't get it, what's wrong?
I'm receiving an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function`

I've tried everything I've find in docs or in gitHub issues:

```
this.transitionTo('someRoute', {objectId: 'asdf'})
this.context.transitionTo('someRoute', {objectId: 'asdf'})
this.context.route.transitionTo('someRoute', {objectId: 'asdf'})
etc.
```

the route and the param is correct, it works fine in this case:

```
<Link to="'someRoute" params={{objectId: 'asdf}}
```

p.s. react-router, react and other libraries is up to date

Answer (score 4):

The `Navigation` component is a Mixin and needs to be added to the component accordingly. If you want to bypass the Mixin (which I feel is the direction React-Router is going) you need to set the contextTypes on the component like so:

```
var ResourceCard = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.func
    }, ...
```

then you can call `this.context.router.transitionTo`.

Answer (score 2):

This works with react 0.14.2 and react-router 1.0.3

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link } from 'react-router';

export default class ResourceCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.routeHandler.bind(this)}>
            LINK
            </div>                  
            );
    }
    routeHandler(){
        this.props.history.pushState(null, '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there's no mixin support for ES6 as of now , you need to change a few things to make it work .`router` is an opt-in context type so you will have to explicitly define `contextTypes` of the class . Then in your `constructor` You will have to pass `context` and `props` to super class. And while calling transitionTo you'll have to use `this.context.router.transitionTo` . and you **don't** need to import `Navigation`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link } from 'react-router';

export default class ResourceCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div onClick={this.routeHandler.bind(this)}>
                LINK
                </div>                  
        );
    }
    routeHandler(){
        this.context.router.transitionTo('someRoute', {objectId: 'asdf'})
    }
}

ResourceCard.contextTypes = {
  router: function contextType() {
    return React.PropTypes.func.isRequired;
  }
};
```

Comment: I try your solution but still got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined`

Comment: You are missing something . Can I look at your code ?

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281070/react-redux-how-to-redirect-to-specific-page-using-react-router I have adjust it to your answer but still same error returned

Comment: NewStock.contextTypes declaration missing in your code , And I also see no constructor in your class. Please read my answer properly and It will definitely work.