# React-router: "Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use `webpack`, `ES6`, `react-router` library and `Link` component for my links. I want to "transit" with parent div of link element, but when I click on div I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539349/how-to-emulate-window-location-with-react-router-and-es6-classes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033247/react-router-transitionto-is-not-a-function) thread.

**NavBar.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, DefaultRoute, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;

var CustomersIcon = require("./icons").CustomersIcon;

export class NavBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
  }

  _openLink() {
      this.context.router.transitionTo('/');
  }

  render() {
    return (
         <div className="menu-item-wrapper" onClick={this._openLink.bind(this)}>
             <CustomersIcon />
             <Link to="/customers" activeClassName="active" ref="customersLink">Customers</Link> 
          </div>
    );     
  }
}

NavBar.contextTypes = {
  router: function contextType() {
    return React.PropTypes.func.isRequired;
  }
};
```

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? Also, `router: function contextType() { ... }` should be `router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired`.

Comment: I use `1.0.0-rc3` version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses the old router API. The API changed a lot from 0.13 to 1.0.0RC.

You want to retrieve the `history` object from context:

```js
NavBar.contextTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

And to transition to another url, from within a NavBar method:

```js
this.context.history.pushState(null, '/');
```

See the [History Mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#history-mixin) API.

You can also specify a more precise `history` contextType using the `history` propType exposed by the library:

```js
var RouterPropTypes = require('react-router').PropTypes;

Navbar.contextTypes = {
  history: RouterPropTypes.history,
};
```

Comment: Aren't Mixins being moved out of React in ES6 though?

Comment: @NickPineda There are no plans to get rid of mixins at the moment. While it is true that components as ES6 classes or pure functions do not support mixins, there are other ways to implement mixin-like functionality. See https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750.

Answer (score 2):

`router` was removed from context in 1.0 version (see [upgrade doc here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#navigation-mixin)) Now in context you have `history` and `location` (see [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc3/modules/RoutingContext.js#L26)). Try this:

```js
this.context.history.pushState(null, '/');
//...
NavBar.contextTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `contextTypes` looks wrong. It should be

```
NavBar.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the React Router 1.0 there is no router on the `context` anymore. It was replaced by `location`:

```jsx
NavBar.contextTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

you can find more about the changes in the 1.0 version in the [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#state-mixin).

Also there is no `transitionTo` you would use `history` for that and do something like: `this.history.pushState(null, '/somePath')`. Definitely check the Upgrade Guide.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863577/3186263) provides the way to programmatically redirect with react-router 2.0.0.

Relevant bit:

`import { browserHistory } from './react-router'
browserHistory.push('/some/path')`