# Required context `router` was not specified. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, ecmascript-harmony

My app is ES6 React application with react-router. I want to redirect user to a different page after a small delay. Here is my React component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigation } from 'react-router'

export default class Component extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <div>Component content</div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // TODO: redirect to homepage
            console.log('redirecting...');
            this.context.router.transitionTo('homepage');
        }, 1000);
    }

}

Component.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

And react-router routing table:

```
render(
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={ App }>
            <IndexRoute component={ Component } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

The issue is that 'router' property is not passed into the component. Chrome console's content is:

```
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Component`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.
redirecting...
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined
```

React version is 0.14.2, react-router version is 1.0.0-rc4
Where do I make mistake?

Comment: I followed advice from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033247/react-router-transitionto-is-not-a-function/33008706#33008706 created constructor and changed value of 'router' context type, but the result is 'transitionTo' is still not available.

Comment: PayPal developers had similar issue but it was closed https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/issues/82

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not a react-router expert by any means, but I had the same issue earlier today. I am using React 0.14.2 and React-Router 1.0 (this just came out in the last couple of days, if not more recently). While debugging I noticed that the props on the React component includes history (the new style of navigation - https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md)

I am also using TypeScript, but my code looks like the following:

```
import React = require('react');
import Header = require('./common/header.tsx');

var ReactRouter = require('react-router');

interface Props extends React.Props<Home> {
    history: any
}

class Home extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header.Header MenuItems={[]} />
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Utility</h1>
                    <p>Click on one of the options below to get started...</p>
                    {<a className="btn btn-lg" onClick={() => this.props.history.pushState(null, '/remoteaccess') }>Remote Access</a>}
                    {<a className="btn btn-lg" onClick={() => this.props.history.pushState(null, '/bridge') }>Bridge</a>}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm inclined to say that `this.context.router` doesn't exist anymore. I've run into the same problem and it looks like we're supposed to implement these features using `this.context.history` as well as `this.context.location`. If I get something working, I'll try updating this response.

Answer (score 1):

See the [1.0.0 upgrade guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md#state-mixin) and use `this.props.history` with `pushState` or `replaceState`. `context` is used for other components (not route components).
From the upgrade guide :

```
// v1.0
// if you are a route component...
<Route component={Assignment} />

var Assignment = React.createClass({
  foo () {
    this.props.location // contains path information
    this.props.params // contains params
    this.props.history.isActive('/pathToAssignment')
  }
})
```