# React redux how to redirect to specific page using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have made some state in reducers which return a value of `logged_in` which has a boolean value.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export class NewStock extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { router, session } = this.props;
    if (session.userSessionData.get('logged_in') == false) {
      router.transitionTo('/login');
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { router, session } = this.props
    const currentRoute = router.location.pathname
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function select(state) {
  return {
    router: state.router,
    flash: state.flash.get('newStock'),
    newStock: state.newStock,
    session: state.session
  }
}

export default connect(select)(NewStock)
```

This component is on the `/new` path

I want to check everytime this page is visit, it will check if the `logged_in` state is `true` or `false`. if it `false` user will be redirect to `/login` page.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const { router, session } = this.props;
    if (session.userSessionData.get('logged_in') == false) {
      router.transitionTo('/login');
    }
  };
```

But it returns an error that says:

`Uncaught TypeError: router.transitionTo is not a function`

Anyone has the same problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the history context to your component:

```
static contextTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.object,
  history: PropTypes.object
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { session } = this.props;
  if (!session.userSessionData.get('logged_in')) {
    this.context.history.pushState(null, '/login');
  }
};
```

## Update for react-router 2

In react-router 2.0, [you would add the router context instead](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation):

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { session } = this.props;
  if (!session.userSessionData.get('logged_in')) {
    this.context.router.push({
      pathname: '/login'
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: what about solution in react-router 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `pushState(null, '/login')` instead of transitionTo.  Also I would recommend making a Higher Order Component that does this type of authorization for you so you don't have to write that `componentDidMount` logic every time.

Here is an example of the Higher Order Authorization Component I am talking about:  https://github.com/SpencerCDixon/Kira/blob/master/client/config/routes.js#L29-L60

*EDIT* I just realized you arn't using redux-router.  But I would recommend either using redux-router or redux-simple-router in combination with react router